# my variable is called in an if statement to test if it is true, but i get local variable 'runningverify' referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm working on a discord bot. it kind of worked before i made changes but i couldn't really update it for what i wanted it to be with the configuration it was in. i have done a lot of looking but i can't really find a problem & solution that help me.

the variable is first declared as a global here:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
global runningverify
runningverify = True
    # ...
```

then, within

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

it is declared when someone sends a message in a specific channel to, well, run the verify process.

```
 if (message.channel.id == redacted):
    runningverify = True
        #...
```

then, within a different channel and after someone sends a message in the other channel ^^^ use the variable runningverify again to check if it is running so as to not execute the process if no one is requesting verification and break the bot.

```
if (message.channel.id == redacted):
    if message.content == 'verify':
        if runningverify == True: #ERROR HERE
            #...
```

however, it breaks the bot anyway.

the original way i did it (before reconfiguration) was basically the same, so i have no clue what i'm doing wrong. the only thing i updated was who had to type 'verify' and moved somethings around. if it worked before i have no clue why it isn't working now.

Comment: The `global` declaration needs to be in any function that wants to modify it.  You don't need it at the top-level outside of any function (where it will have no effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare global runningverify inside the function where the loop  is executed